# Issue with CarrierWave and AWS S3.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have deployed my app on Ninefold, but it crashes when I try uploading pictures. The logs suggest that I'm missing my AWS credentials:

```
ArgumentError (Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
```

But I'm fairly sure I've got them set up correctly using Fog and my .env file. CarrierWave initializer looks like this at the moment:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                             # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['S3_KEY'],                     # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['S3_SECRET'],                  # required
    :region                 => 'us-east-1'                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east1'
    }
    config.fog_directory  = ENV['S3_BUCKET'],                     # required
end
```

Any suggestions on how to get this working correctly? Don't know what other info to give but if you need more info to help me solve let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the environment variables in your app?

You need to add some variables with the relevant names in the Environment Variables section under the app deploy.

```
S3_KEY
S3_SECRET
S3_BUCKET
```

You amazon account should have the relevant details.